# sql subquery syntax asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql

I am trying to excute this sql query

```
Dim str As String = "UPDATE table1 SET " & _
            "number = '" & strc & "'," & _
            "code = '" & "123" & "'," & _
            "line= '" & dd1.text & "'," & _
            "sellr = '" & txtrun.text & "'," & _
            "endu= '" & txtex1.value+txtex2.value & "'" & _
             "WHERE number IN (select table1.number" & _
"FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.number = table2.number" & _
"WHERE ((table1.username)='" &  session("username") & "' AND (table1.pass)='" & session("pass") & "' AND (table2.sellnum)='" & session("sellnum") & "'));"
```

there is a Syntax error  in query expression and this is te first time I am using nested subquery

all the field are getting String values

So if someone can tell me what is the right approach to write this query I will be very grateful

Comment: Your code is wide open to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should use parameterized queries.

Comment: Agree Oded... Create a Stored Procedure which takes those parameters and does the update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing spaces after `table1.number` and `table2.number` fields in the subquery.

I don't know where you're using this query, but you might want to read about [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). When you stick strings together to build SQL, your code may be vulnerable to malicious users who put SQL code into the fields of your application.

Comment: Another useful link on SQL injection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain

Comment: Think SQL Injection may be an issue?

Comment: Thanks Don ,it working like charm! by the way isnt it enough if I check the user input (to prevent sql injection)?

Comment: Perhaps, @baaroz, but it's usually easier and more effective to use parameterized queries or stored procedures. They will do all the checking for you.